# Additional Arguments to dynamic reconfigure callback

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, camera-driver, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(also posted as issue on dynamic reconfigure git, possibly not appropriate for there) I am trying to use dynamic configure to set some camera parameters. I would like to pass a pointer to the camera object into the callback, so that I can use it's methods for setting the camera values. Is it possible to pass additional arguments to the dynamic reconfigure callback?
Callback:

```
void dr_callback(camera_node::dynamic_reconfig &parameters, uint32_t levels){
// set global object of parameters
}
```

Binding:

```
dr_callback = boost::bind(dr_callback, _1, _2);
dr_server.setCallback(dr_callback);
```

ideal callback:

```
void dr_callback_function(jai_camera_node::dynamic_reconfigConfig &parameters, uint32_t levels, cam_type *cam){
// use camera member functions to change values
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316242/additional-arguments-to-dynamic-reconfigure-callback./) by [ben2789](https://answers.ros.org/users/40123/ben2789/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

passing a reference to the camera as an additional argument works fine. This is because the result of bind(function, _1 , _2, camera_ptr) is a two parameter function pointer which can be accepted by setCallback().

---

Originally posted by [ben2789](https://answers.ros.org/users/40123/ben2789/) with karma: 16 on 2019-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0